# How to set M2_HOME and PATH env. variables on OS X for Maven permanently to prevent them being deleted after Terminal is restarted

Tags: maven

I faced with issue that I cannot set `M2_HOME` and `PATH` env. variables on OS X for Maven permanently. They are being deleted each time Terminal is restarted. How to deal with it?

After Terminal is restarted I have:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

and nothing for `$M2_HOME`

Edit: 
I followed steps from official Maven install page and created ~/.bash_profile with following

```
export M2_HOME=$(/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.2/libexec)
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

But it does not work at all. 
echo $M2_HOME or any other variable gives empty line.

Comment: Possibly you're not running bash? echo $SHELL, and make sure that file is actually being sourced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply made it different. I unpackaged the apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.tar.gz into `/usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.2.2` and created a link in `/usr/share` like this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root   wheel    34 Jun 29 00:38 maven -> /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.1.1
```

and added/change the following line in my `.profile` file (my home folder)

```
PATH=/usr/share/maven/bin:$PATH
```

This gaves me the opportunity to change the underlying Maven version simply by changing the above link.

Comment: I am presently in the /usr/share folder. What does it mean to "create a link"?  I don't know where to add the line lrwxr-xr-x    1 root   wheel    34 Jun 29 00:38 maven -> /usr/share/java/apache-maven-3.1.1

Answer (score 17):

You need to add your maven path in bash_profile file

In the Terminal type the following:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

In the window that opens add path as:

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Press CTRL_X and then Y to save. Press Enter.

On the terminal type:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
echo $M2_HOME
```

You will see that the path appears to be set.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a great article on how to set up HOME for MAVNE with brew:

https://wilsonmar.github.io/maven-on-macos/

To install the latest version:

```
brew update
brew install maven

mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T03:58:13-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.2/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Confirm the path:

Substitute the version (3.5.2) with the version you just installed:

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.2/libexec/bin
ls
```

mvn files should be listed:

```
m2.conf     mvn      mvnDebug mvnyjp
```

Open using a text editor, substituting subl (for Sublime) with atom or vim:

```
cd $HOME
subl .bash_profile
```

Add the following to under export PATH=, changing the version (3.5.2) to whatever appears above:

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.2/libexec
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```